# Grab id of div, which is set as a number through template literal

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid

Having a slight issue, trying to `document.getElementById()`, of a div, where the ID is set as a number.

You can see below, I'm looping through an object in my database and displaying each element in the DOM.  I'm then giving each div, an id, (which is a number `lastTask.id`):

```
  function displayLastTask(lastTask) {
    console.log(lastTask);
    individualTasks +=
      `<div class="todoStyle">
        <p>Date: ${lastTask.date}: Task: ${lastTask.todo}</p>
        <p><button class="deleteButton" id=${lastTask.id}>Delete</button>
      </div>`;
    tasksContainer.innerHTML = individualTasks;
    return tasksContainer;
  }
```

I'm doing this, because later, I want to grab my delete button by its ID/object array number.  (And only delete an object in the database, if its ID matches).

Anyway, the question I have, is how can I do a `document.getElementById()`, if it is a number? `toString` didn't work. Not sure if this is possible at all, if the ID is a number...

Here's what I'm trying:

```
    for (var i = 0, len = res.length; i < len; i++) {
      lookup[res[i].id] = res[i];

      const id = toString(res[i].id);

      document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('clicked');
      });
    }
```

Which returns the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Have tried a few variations with no luck.

Comment: when you `console.log(id)` (before trying to get the element) what it shows?

Comment: Have you tried just doing `document.getElementById(res[i].id).addEventListener...`? The `toString` function is not a standalone function if you wanted to call it, you'd call it as `const id = res[i].id.toString();` If you're supporting older browsers, you're probably better off using a string prefix though.

Comment: @CalvinNunes - I get the id, but as a number. EG here's a console log.... id 1

Comment: What is the order of calling those pieces of code? If `addEventListener` happens before `displayLastTask` then object is not there yet. In that case `null` is returned.

Comment: weird, because using `.getElementById(number)` should not be a problem

Comment: I checked in the newest chrome and `<div id="42"></div>` can be grabbed by `document.getElementById(42)` or `document.getElementById('42')`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey- With both your suggestions, I get the same null type errror..... "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't add an event listener to every single item.
You can do this with event bubbling.

Just add an event listener to a parentNode of your element.
E.g.

```
document.querySelector('#parent').addEventListener('click', event => { 
    console.log(event.target.parentNode.id); 
})
```

If for some reason you have to select a parent over the direct parent of that element, because you are creating the parent of your item more than once, you just log the following: `console.log(event.target.parentNode.parentNode.id);`.

If it's even higher up, you just keep adding parentNodes.

Just play around with those settings until you find what you were looking for.

Hopefully, my explanation was understandable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the id with "":

```
  function displayLastTask(lastTask) {
    console.log(lastTask);
    individualTasks +=
      `<div class="todoStyle">
        <p>Date: ${lastTask.date}: Task: ${lastTask.todo}</p>
        <p><button class="deleteButton" id="${lastTask.id}">Delete</button>
      </div>`;
    tasksContainer.innerHTML = individualTasks;
    return tasksContainer;
  }
```